# Multiple icon entries on Info.plist file in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, icons

When I import a project that started on Xcode 3 on Xcode 4, it ads another set of entries for the icons on the *Info.plist* file. Something like this:

[image]

and some times there is also another entry called `"Icon file"` (file on the singular, not plural), alone.

Are all these entries required?

Another question: why the launch images `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png` are added to the icon sections?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need the entry `Icon files` (plural) with all your icons (57x57,72x72,114x114,144x144).
You may delete the `Icon files (iOS 5)` as well as the `Icon file` (singular).

The `Default.png`'s in that section is totally wrong and was maybe placed there because of a bug  in Xcode.

Comment: Is there any reason I should delete the *Icon files (iOS 5)* entry? Is this explained anywhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like Jonas said, you can delete the (iOS 5) part.

However, this is clearly a new addition, and most likely Apple is going forward with these changes for a reason.

I would clean it up and keep it for forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to specify @2x versions, they will be picked automatically for ipads,[dev page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) just list 1x versions in items there. 
item 0: Icon - it is 57x57
item 1: Icon-72 - it is 72x72
item 2: Icon-Small - it is 29-29
item 3: Icon-Small-50 -it is 50x50

add these files in .png format to your proj as well as @2x so 8 of them all together.

add Default.png and its 2x version to proj too and in launch image specify only Default.png

B